# Possible memoryleak in ConcurrentBag?

Tags: .net, concurrency

I've been reading into the new concurrent collections and esspecially the ConcurrentBag got my attention. Since the ConcurrentBag internally holds a local set on each individual thread using it to keep track of the items, this means that when the thread itself gets out of scope, it will still be referenced in memory by the ConcurrentBag. This in turn means both memory claimed by the thread, as well as native resources? (excuse me for not knowing the exact inner workings of the .NET thread object)

I can assume a usecase where you have 1 global ConcurrentBack for a multithreaded webservice where you have alot of clients adding tasks. These tasks are added by threads on the threadpool. Now the threadpool is a very efficient way to manage threads but it does remove and create Threads based on the amount of work. Therefore, such a webservice can at times find itself in trouble since the underlying bag is still referencing to many should be-destroyed threads.

I created a quick app to test this behavior:

```
    static ConcurrentBag<int> bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    static void FillBag() { for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { bag.Add(i); } }
    static void PrintState() { Console.WriteLine("Bag size is: {0}", bag.Count); }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var remote = new Thread(x =>
        {
            FillBag();
            PrintState();
        });
        // empty bag
        PrintState();
        // first 100 items are added on main thread
        FillBag();
        PrintState();
        // second 100 items are added on remote thread
        remote.Start();
        remote.Join();
        // since the remote thread is gone out of scope, what happened to its local storage which is part of the bag?
        PrintState();
        // now force a cleanup
        WeakReference weakRemoteReference = new WeakReference(remote); 
        remote = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        // Now check if the thread still exists
        if (weakRemoteReference.IsAlive)
            Console.WriteLine("Remote thread still exists");
        PrintState();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And the output confirms my story:

```
Bag size is: 0
Bag size is: 100
Bag size is: 200
Bag size is: 200
Remote thread still exists
Bag size is: 200
```

Is this behavior to be expected, did i make a mistake in my test or can this be considered a design flaw?

Comment: Note that i name the remote thread is gone out of scope, ofcourse its still in scope and should say:  "Since the remote thread is finished"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ConcurrentBag` does indeed keep things in thread local storage, and if you abandon threads it *can* cause a memory leak.  However, the implementation is able to "steal" items from one thread's list to give to another thread.  You can see this in action if you write the following:

```
ConcurrentBag<int> MyBag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

void DoIt()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        MyBag.Add(i);
    }

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(EmptyBag);

    Console.Write("Press Enter:");
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} items in bag", MyBag.Count);
}

void EmptyBag(object state)
{
    int take;
    while (MyBag.TryTake(out take))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(take);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Bag is empty");
}
```

If you run that program and wait until the "Bag is empty" message before you hit Enter, you'll see that the bag is indeed emptied.

So, as long as there's one thread reading from the bag, it *will* be emptied eventually.  Even if all the items were added by other threads.

So, yes, there's a possible memory leak.  In practice, though, if multiple threads are accessing the bag, it's likely not a concern.

Comment: I'm guessing two threads are here, and the QueueUserWorkItem spawns a new thread.  Which thread is the one that is leaking (source, or the stolen copy)? How can I interrupt this process and shutdown cleanly?  I'm using a cancelation token in a task...

Comment: @makerofthings7: In this example code, the main thread owns the bag, and the thread spawned by `QueueUserWorkItem` empties the bag. Nothing's leaking in this example. In general, there will be a leak if you add things to the bag and don't take them out. You might consider posting a question if you want more information.